# Issue with Wins and Losses... (must have easygui)

Tags: python, easygui

```
ComputerChoice = ""
x = 0
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0
rounds = 0
abc = 0
CurrentStatus = 'started'

Choices = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
#################################################
def computerchoice(ComputerChoice, Choices, UserChoice): #number
          listthing = Choices[:]
          #listthing.remove[UserChoice]
          ComputerChoice = random.choice(listthing)
          ComputerChoice = Choices.index(ComputerChoice)
          return ComputerChoice
#################################################
import easygui
import random
easygui.msgbox( "Hello, This is a standard game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.","Welcome!","Next>>>")

while x == 0:
         UserChoice = easygui.buttonbox(' __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ You just ' +CurrentStatus+ '. __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ \n You currently have won '+str(wins)+ ' times, lost ' +str(losses)+' times, and tied '+ str(ties)+' times.  \n\n\nClick your next move: ','Choice Picker 2000',['Rock','Paper','Scissors','Done'])
         UserChoice = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors','Done'].index(UserChoice)
         ComputerChoice = computerchoice(ComputerChoice, Choices, UserChoice)
         if UserChoice == ComputerChoice:
                  ties = ties +1
                  rounds = rounds +1
                  CurrentStatus = "Tied"


         if UserChoice== 3:
                  x = 1
                  break

         elif UserChoice > ComputerChoice and UserChoice + ComputerChoice != 4:
                  wins = wins +1
                  rounds = rounds + 1
                  CurrentStatus = "Won"

         elif UserChoice < ComputerChoice and UserChoice + ComputerChoice != 4:
                  losses = losses +1
                  rounds = rounds +1
                  CurrentStatus = "Lost"

         elif UserChoice + ComputerChoice ==4 and UserChoice != ComputerChoice:
                  if Userchoice == 1:
                           score = score +1
                           rounds = rounds +1
                           CurrentStatus = "Won"
                  elif ComputerChoice == 1:
                          losses = losses +1
                          rounds = rounds +1

                          CurrentStatus = "Lost"


result = ["Cool.","Okay.","I am a failure"]
if wins>losses:
         easygui.msgbox("You won "+str(wins)+ " times, lost " +str(losses)+" times, tied "+ str(ties)+ " and won " +str(int(float(wins)/float(rounds)*100))+ "% of the time.","",result[0])
elif wins==losses:
         easygui.msgbox("You won "+str(wins)+ " times, lost " +str(losses)+" times, tied "+ str(ties)+ " and won " +str(int(float(wins)/float(rounds)*100))+ "% of the time.","",result[1])
elif wins<losses:
         easygui.msgbox("You won "+str(wins)+ " times, lost " +str(losses)+" times, tied "+ str(ties)+ " and won " +str(int(float(wins)/float(rounds)*100))+ "% of the time.","",result[2])
```

When I run this it works okay, but if you press "Rock", then you will always tie/lose, never win. If you press "Scissors", then you will always tie/win, never lose.
       I am pretty sure this is the same problem, but if someone can look over it, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for determining a winner seems somewhat convoluted. Maybe try simplifying and extracting some of it off to a helper function.

(This function is purposely unnecessarily verbose)

```
def userWon(userChoice, computerChoice):
    if (userChoice == (computerChoice + 1 % 3)):
        return True
    if (computerChoice == (userChoice + 1 % 3)):
        return False
    if (computerChoice == userChoice):
        return None
```

Note that your rock-paper-scissors list is in the order such that for any given choice at position `c`, the choice that beats that is at position `c + 1 mod 3`. Using that, you can use this helper function which will return `True` if the user won, `False` if they lost, and `None` if it's a tie.

Then you can just check for the Quit option before calling this.